# Como listar todos arquivos de um diretório do servidor em ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Quero saber como faço para criar um `List<string>` com os nomes dos arquivos de um determinado diretório.

O serviço está hospedado em um servidor compartilhado, publicado no meu `httpdocs`.

Tenho varias imagens dentro de `httpdocs/img/imagens`.

Como eu acesso esse diretório?

Código do Controler:

```
DirectoryInfo diretorio = new DirectoryInfo("~/img/imagens/");
FileInfo[] arquivos = diretorio.GetFiles();
```

Erro:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
    Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\~\img\imagens'.
</string>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É quase isso. Mude para:

```
DirectoryInfo diretorio = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/img/imagens/"));
FileInfo[] arquivos = diretorio.GetFiles();
```

[Veja mais aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Para completar, `Server.MapPath` fica dentro de `HttpContext.Current`, então sempre usar `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` ou fazer o `using`